# PHP/CURL - Making a POST request to another page and following the URL

Tags: php, redirect, curl, header

I am going to try and explain this as best I can, I hope that I make sense as English is not my first language.

Lets say that I have a form on page 1 which contains these 3 inputs:

```
$_POST["name"];
$_POST["amount"];
$_POST["email"];
```

And on a second page process.php I also have another input:

```
$_POST["message"];
```

And finally on an external website there is a form that I want to POST to without having to type anything into their system:

```
<form action="display.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="name"><br>
 <input type="text" name="amount"><br>
 <input type="text" name="email"><br>
 <input type="text" name="message"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I then want to be able to be automatically redirected to www.example.com/display.php **from my process.php page and submit the form automatically** and be able to see all of my information that I just entered

Example of what display.php looks like:

[Display.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7JRD.png)

I do not have access to the code on the external website or display.php so this means that I cannot edit the code or use any sessions.

**I hope that you understand me and that you could be able to help me, I would be so grateful if you could help me!**

EDIT:

I tested some code that I was given in an answer and looks promising but it didn't pass the POST data to the external page (Which is not external for testing purposes)

Here is the code used to test below:

process.php

```
<?php
$_POST["name"] = "name";
$_POST["amount"] = "amount";
$_POST["email"] = "email";
$_POST["message"] = "message";

$post = array();
$post[] = "name=" . $_POST["name"];
$post[] = "amount=" . $_POST["amount"];
$post[] = "email=" . $_POST["email"];
$post[] = "message=" . $_POST["message"];

$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/display');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
header('Content-Type: text/html');
echo curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

display.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST["name"];
echo $_POST["amount"];
echo $_POST["email"];
echo $_POST["message"];
?>
```

But for some reason this did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?  It assumes name, amount and email will be posted to process.php

Added trouble shooting code.

**process.php**

```
 <?php

 //[put database queries here]

 // $message = ??????????????????


$message = 'Message';

$post = array(
'name'=>$_POST['name'],
'amount'=>$_POST['amount'],
'email'=>$_POST['email'],
'message'=>$message);

$ch = curl_init('http://www.example.com/display.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");

header('Content-Type: text/html');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $data;
?>
```

### This was tested and works too

does the redirect to the actual site.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$amount = $_POST["amount"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

echo <<< EOT
<html><head><style></style></head><body>
<form id="form" action="http://www.example.com/display.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="$name"/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="$amount"/>
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="$email"/>
<input type="hidden" name="message" value="$message"/>
</form>

<script>document.getElementById("form").submit();</script>
</body></html>
EOT;

?>
```

Comment: Page 1 is a form just like the external website, this is where a user enters their name, email and amount.

Comment: The form then goes to process.php and adds the users details to a database (Process.php will set a predefined message that is not set by the user)

Comment: And I then want process.php to redirect to display.php (Bypassing the form on the external website)

Comment: So I need to somehow pass this POST data to display.php without using a HTML form at all, this is what I want to do, and I was hoping that it was possible.

Comment: Many thanks, I hope you understand me slightly better, thanks!

Comment: I just tried your code but it didn't pass the POST data over? Your code looks promising though and along the lines of what I need to achieve!

Comment: I edited my post for you so you could see the code I tested with!

Comment: <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: name in <b>D:\Servers\WebServer\htdocs\display.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />

Comment: I am using htaccess you see, so this means that I don't have any .php links on my URL

Comment: Neither does the external website

Comment: The POST data does not seem to be going through on the external website! (That is just an internal test at the moment as you can see my code in the edit)

Comment: If I have .php it won't work due to htaccess rules you see

Comment: Why does your code not work? It looks promising but the POSTS that are being echoed are undefined?

Comment: I am looking forward to your response as I defiantly think you will be able to help me solve my problem!

Comment: YOU GENIUS! IT WORKED!

Comment: What was wrong with it before buddy? This is just great :)

Comment: The problem was the $post array was not formed correctly so curl did not pass the POST data.

Comment: You are a genius sir, I also checked out your website and listened to some of your music!

Comment: Thanks so much! You are a great person, I selected your answer of course, thanks again, I owe you one!

Comment: Removed the trouble shooting code.  Changed content-type from plain to html

Comment: Is there any way for it to redirect to the actual page though? As it's still technically on the processing page, but other than that is does exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can have `process.php` create and submit a form using JavaScript with something like this:

```
<form id="form" action="display.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?= $_POST["name"] ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?= $_POST["amount"] ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?= $_POST["email"] ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="message" value="<?= $_POST["message"] ?>">
</form>

<script>document.getElementById("form").submit();</script>
```

Hope I helped!
-CM

Comment: I would like to know how I would follow this data using CURL, this wouldn't work for the project I am working on as it's a bit more complicated than that, thank you very much for the answer though!

Comment: Also, process.php does not have a form, only the first page does!

Comment: process.php is all CURL and the message is pre-defined, I need to redirect to display.php while having all of the POST data come with the user

Comment: @rakupu I updated my answer to one that should fit better for you.

Answer (score 0):

The script on the server cannot POST to a page the same way a browser can, so strictly speaking what you’re asking for can’t be done.  You can do similar things that may still solve your problem...

1) process.php can use Curl to call display.php and display the results directly on process.php

2) the original page with the form can do some Ajax (or similar) to determine what $message should be, then add it as a Hidden input via JavaScript, and only then submit the form. No intermediate process.php form— we go straight to display.php

I think #2 will be best for the situation you describe